# Sampling for hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling

I want to perform hypothesis test (Large Sample Tests for difference of two means) for two columns in my dataset. I want to use Simple Random Sampling to get my sample of 100 from 592 rows of the dataset (for two columns).Should i pick my sample with replacement or without replacement?

Comment: Why isn't your data frame the sample?

Comment: Why not use all 592 rows?

Comment: because i want to perform hypothesis test for large sample using z-test(for means). And according to my textbook, we calculate the p-value of our hypothesis based on the mean obtained from a sample. So i figured we need a sample